# is there a better way to bind two events, but only triggers when either one is true

Tags: jquery, function

THis is what i currently have

```
click = false;

if click
    $(el).on('click', 'li', {})
else
    $(el).on('hover', 'li', {})
```

both click and hover actually triggers the same function, is there a more minimal way to write this such as

```
$(el).on('click, hover', 'li' {})
```

but still able to control it through var click;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do ternaries:

```
var click = false;
$(el).on((click)?'click':'hover', 'li',function(){...})
```

Answer (score 0):

If your function takes the event as the first argument (e.g. `function (e) {…`) then you can check `e.type` to see if it is "hover" or "click" and then bind the handler as in your second example and check that this values matches the appropriate event as determined by `click`.